# How to get the upcoming post ID from front end?

Tags: custom-post-types, uploads, front-end, id

Searching with "Next Post ID" is giving me the Previous/Next Post Navigation, but my question is not related to that.

In WordPress Admin panel, when we're attempting to create a new post the post is been automatically saved as 'auto-draft' and the post ID is been placed within the form as a hidden field named `post_id`. So when the post is submitted and the `$_REQUEST['post_id']` is been isset.

I'm trying to move uploaded attachments with a Custom Post Type to it's designated directory under `uploads/` like `uploads/my-dir/my-item-{post_id}`. I'm following [Rian Rietveld's snippet](https://gist.github.com/rianrietveld/8705908) for the move. And attachments from admin panel is moving perfectly:

```
/**
 * Set the attachment Upload path.
 *
 * Set a custom upload path for the post attachments for
 * easy management.
 *
 * @param array $upload Default directory.
 *
 * @author Rian Rietveld
 * @link   https://gist.github.com/rianrietveld/8705908
 *
 * @return array Defined directory for the App.
 */
public function my_attachment_dir( $upload ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['post_id'] ) ) {
        $id = $_REQUEST['post_id'];

        // Check whether the posttype is ours.
        if ( 'my-cpt' === get_post_type( $id ) ) {
            $cpt_directory = "my-item-{$id}";
            $upload['subdir'] = "/my-dir/{$cpt_directory}";
        }

        $upload['path'] = $upload['basedir'] . $upload['subdir'];
        $upload['url']  = $upload['baseurl'] . $upload['subdir'];
    }

    return $upload;
}

add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'my_attachment_dir' );
```

But the issue is, I can't pass a hidden field with post ID from the front end, so the `$_REQUEST['post_id']` is getting unset, and the filter is not working. The attachments are uploading to its typical year-month directory.

The question I have, could be answered by any of the following:

1. How can I get the upcoming post ID in front end? or,
2. How to add filter to [`upload_dir`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/upload_dir/) with a makeshift `$post_id` instead of passing through `$_REQUEST`?

Comment: Did you find the solution of it?

Comment: Not yet. But got a function that returns the auto draft post id, but can't remember that now. The task is pending yet. :( A possible workaround could be to save an auto-draft post and get that ID to proceed with.